# How to get a single colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code for each for loop i'm getting a single colorbar. But I want to represent the following data with a single colorbar.

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
h_1 = np.load("./Result_2D/disorder.npy")
h = h_1[0:2]
print("h: ",h)
for k in range(len(h)):
    h_val = round(h[k],1)
    KL=np.load("./KL_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("KL: ",KL[0:5])
    E = np.load("./E_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("E_shape: ",E[0:5])
    W =np.load("./W_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("W: ",W[0:5])
    sc= ax.scatter(E,W,c=KL,cmap='RdBu_r')
    plt.colorbar(sc)`
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

here is some example code of how to print multiple scatter sets with the same single colorbar

```
pltrange = np.logspace(1, 2, num=20) #or use np.linspace, or provide a range of values (based on the limits of your data)
lbrange = pltrange[::2] #labels for colorbar

ax.scatter(x=stream['Dist'], y=stream['Depth'], s=50,
           c=stream['Sand Concentration (mg/l)'],
           cmap='rainbow', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1,
           vmin=pltrange[0],vmax=pltrange[-1]) #note the vmin and vmax, do this for all scatter sets

cb = fig.colorbar(ax=ax, ticks=lbrange, pad=0.01) #display colorbar, keep outside loop
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(['{:.1f}'.format(i) for i in lbrange]) #format labels if desired
```

I realize it's not exactly formatted for your code but..it's the exact same principle and I'm posting this from bed :) so I think you could make the necessary adaptations

Comment: I read in a post that after finding min,max value of a range and using norm = plt.Normalize(min_, max_) and sc=plt.scatter= ax.scatter(E,W,c=KL,cmap='RdBu_r',norm=norm) we get a single colorbar. Is it a proper way to do this,? In your post you have used logspace what is the purpose of that?

Comment: you can use a linspace or define your own array there, I just used a logarithmic scale for my colorbar due to the data I had..and honestly I'm not sure about your comment

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
h_1 = np.load("./Result_2D/disorder.npy")
h = h_1[0:2]
print("h: ",h)
for k in range(len(h)):
    h_val = round(h[k],1)
    KL=np.load("./KL_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("KL: ",KL[0:5])
    E = np.load("./E_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("E_shape: ",E[0:5])
    W =np.load("./W_%s.npy"%h_val)
    print("W: ",W[0:5])
    sc= ax.scatter(E,W,c=KL,cmap='RdBu_r')
plt.colorbar(sc)
```

Comment: In my code when k==0 shape of KL,E and W is 19 and when  k==1 shape of Kl,E and W is 30. Is it appropriate to use a single color bar with these shapes? if I print plt.colorbar outside the loop it only shows colorbar for the last loop?

Comment: for different `k` , the different color bar shows the different range. So you want use a single bar to show all of the different value range?

Comment: Yes I want to choose single color bar to show all of the different values.

Comment: Secondly I showed my data as scatter points.  if possible, I want to show them as merging colors. But then how I can do that in matplotlib? The figure that I posted shows points for for 2 for loops but in my actual plot I have to run for loop 10 times so these colored lines are close to each other